# How can I add an extension AND it's settings to chrome driver extensions?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using python, selenium and chromedriver to create a program that fills out a form for me. There is a certain chrome extension I would like to use. The extension I'm talking about is called "Autofill" it has a little lightning bolt picture. I have a "profile" on the extension that fills out a bunch of things on a form at once. I know how to add the extension to chromedriver, but when I do it doesn't save the profile with all the information. I know there are work-arounds to this problem where you can fill it out with commands, but it needs to be very fast and "Autofill" is fast.

Answer (score 2):

We will try to be even more helpful if you share the code sample . As far as I understand; you could use chrome webdriver options like that.

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


executable_path = "path_chromedriver"
os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = executable_path

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_extension('path_of_extension')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=executable_path, chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get("http://google.com")
```

For more information, you should check https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities

Comment: Here's my code: `from selenium import webdriver
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--load-extension=C:\\Users\\Jude\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default\\Extensions\\nlmmgnhgdeffjkdckmikfpnddkbbfkkk\\7.8.0_0')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
driver.get('http://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/all/accessories')` I want to keep the extension the exact same as my regular chrome, and not blank.